# Get seconds of day in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime

In Java we use Joda-Time to get the seconds of a day as an int value (despite the date):

```
date: 10-10-2014 00:00:30 -> second 30 of day
date: 11-10-2014 00:01:30 -> second 90 of day
date: 12-10-2014 00:02:00 -> second 120 of day
```

Is there a way to do the same in PostgresSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `extract()` method:

```
select extract(second from current_timestamp) +
       extract(minute from current_timestamp) * 60 +
       extract(hour from current_timestamp) * 60 * 60;
```

of course this can be put into a function:

```
create or replace function total_seconds(p_timestamp timestamp)
 returns int
as
$$
  select (extract(second from p_timestamp) +
         extract(minute from p_timestamp) * 60 +
         extract(hour from p_timestamp) * 60 * 60)::int;
$$
language sql;
```

more details are in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 10):

[**`extract()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) the `epoch` from the time component after casting to `time` (effectively removing the date component):

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM ts::time) AS seconds_of_day
```

You get the "number of seconds", including fractional seconds if there are any.
Very short and fast.

Test (with timestamps in unambiguous *ISO format*):

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM ts::time) AS seconds_of_day
FROM  (
   VALUES 
     ('2014-10-12 00:00:30'::timestamp)   --    30
   , ('2014-10-12 00:01:30')              --    90
   , ('2014-10-12 00:02:00')              --   120
   , ('2014-10-12 12:00:00')              -- 43200
   , ('1999-12-23 23:59:59')              -- 86399
   , ('1999-12-23 23:59:59.123456')       -- 86399.123456
  ) t(ts);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/crEuM2kN)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/104819)</sub>